# how do i get the gateway MAC address in C on linux?

Tags: c, linux

I have an application that uses raw sockets and I need to construct the ethernet header. Currently I am hard coding the MAC address of my gateway like so:

```
struct ether_header *eh
...
eh->ether_dhost[0] = 0x70;
eh->ether_dhost[1] = 0x97;
eh->ether_dhost[2] = 0x41;
eh->ether_dhost[3] = 0x4b;
eh->ether_dhost[4] = 0x1e;
eh->ether_dhost[5] = 0xc2;
```

I want my code to run on multiple Linux machines so I need an automated way of getting the gateway's MAC address. Can this be done in C? I understand this problem is platform specific. That's not a problem. I don't need a portable solution. I just need it to work on Linux.

Comment: @yano The gateway is not the local machine.

Comment: @interjay ah, of course

Comment: I think you'll need to send an ARP request to convert IP address to MAC (or access the ARP cache if it's there).

Comment: @interjay That seems like a good strategy. Do you know how to do this in C?

Comment: You should use a netlink socket (PF_NETLINK) to get the default route. Then also using a netlink socket you should get the ARP entry for the IP of that default route.

Comment: @Cheatah Sounds great. Can you provide a code example of how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting how I finally solved this. Following the suggestion to use a netlink socket to get the default route I implemented something that gets the default route ip address and then gets the MAC address through an ARP request. The code below does all this and also gets the interface name and does some network communication (send SYN to IP address obtained from a file which is a list of IP addresses - one per line). Here's the code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/if_packet.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>    //Provides declarations for tcp header
#include <netinet/ip.h> //Provides declarations for ip header
#include <netinet/ether.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <asm/types.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
//#include <linux/if_arp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>  //htons etc
#include <time.h>
#include <linux/rtnetlink.h>

#define PROTO_ARP 0x0806
#define ETH2_HEADER_LEN 14
#define HW_TYPE 1
#define MAC_LENGTH 6
#define IPV4_LENGTH 4
#define ARP_REQUEST 0x01
#define ARP_REPLY 0x02
#define BUF_SIZE 60
#define MAX_CONNECTIONS 10000

#define debug(x...) printf(x);printf("\n");
#define info(x...) printf(x);printf("\n");
#define warn(x...) printf(x);printf("\n");
#define err(x...) printf(x);printf("\n");

static char * str_devname= NULL;
static int mode_loss     = 0;
static int c_packet_sz   = 150;
static int c_packet_nb   = 1000;
static int c_buffer_sz   = 1024*8;
static int c_buffer_nb   = 1024;
static int c_sndbuf_sz   = 0;
static int c_send_mask   = 127;
static int c_error       = 0;
static int c_mtu         = 0;
static int mode_thread   = 0;

volatile int fd_socket[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
volatile int data_offset = 0;
volatile struct tpacket_hdr * ps_header_start;
volatile struct sockaddr_ll *ps_sockaddr = NULL;
volatile int shutdown_flag = 0;
int done = 0;
struct tpacket_req s_packet_req;
unsigned char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
struct arp_header *arp_resp = (struct arp_header *) (buffer + ETH2_HEADER_LEN);
char ifname[512];
char ip[512];

/* 
    96 bit (12 bytes) pseudo header needed for tcp header checksum calculation 
*/
struct pseudo_header
{
    u_int32_t source_address;
    u_int32_t dest_address;
    u_int8_t placeholder;
    u_int8_t protocol;
    u_int16_t tcp_length;
};


struct arp_header {
    unsigned short hardware_type;
    unsigned short protocol_type;
    unsigned char hardware_len;
    unsigned char protocol_len;
    unsigned short opcode;
    unsigned char sender_mac[MAC_LENGTH];
    unsigned char sender_ip[IPV4_LENGTH];
    unsigned char target_mac[MAC_LENGTH];
    unsigned char target_ip[IPV4_LENGTH];
};

int rtnl_receive(int fd, struct msghdr *msg, int flags)
{
    int len;

    do { 
        len = recvmsg(fd, msg, flags);
    } while (len < 0 && (errno == EINTR || errno == EAGAIN));

    if (len < 0) {
        perror("Netlink receive failed");
        return -errno;
    }

    if (len == 0) { 
        perror("EOF on netlink");
        return -ENODATA;
    }

    return len;
}

static int rtnl_recvmsg(int fd, struct msghdr *msg, char **answer)
{
    struct iovec *iov = msg->msg_iov;
    char *buf;
    int len;

    iov->iov_base = NULL;
    iov->iov_len = 0;

    len = rtnl_receive(fd, msg, MSG_PEEK | MSG_TRUNC);

    if (len < 0) {
        return len;
    }

    buf = malloc(len);

    if (!buf) {
        perror("malloc failed");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    iov->iov_base = buf;
    iov->iov_len = len;

    len = rtnl_receive(fd, msg, 0);

    if (len < 0) {
        free(buf);
        return len;
    }

    *answer = buf;

    return len;
}

void parse_rtattr(struct rtattr *tb[], int max, struct rtattr *rta, int len)
{
    memset(tb, 0, sizeof(struct rtattr *) * (max + 1));

    while (RTA_OK(rta, len)) {
        if (rta->rta_type <= max) {
            tb[rta->rta_type] = rta;
        }

        rta = RTA_NEXT(rta,len);
    }
}

static inline int rtm_get_table(struct rtmsg *r, struct rtattr **tb)
{
    __u32 table = r->rtm_table;

    if (tb[RTA_TABLE]) {
        table = *(__u32 *)RTA_DATA(tb[RTA_TABLE]);
    }

    return table;
}

void print_route(struct nlmsghdr* nl_header_answer)
{
    struct rtmsg* r = NLMSG_DATA(nl_header_answer);
    int len = nl_header_answer->nlmsg_len;
    struct rtattr* tb[RTA_MAX+1];
    int table;
    char buf[256];

    len -= NLMSG_LENGTH(sizeof(*r));

    if (len < 0) {
        perror("Wrong message length");
        return;
    }
    
    parse_rtattr(tb, RTA_MAX, RTM_RTA(r), len);

    table = rtm_get_table(r, tb);

    if (r->rtm_family != AF_INET && table != RT_TABLE_MAIN) {
        return;
    }

    if (tb[RTA_DST]) {
        if ((r->rtm_dst_len != 24) && (r->rtm_dst_len != 16)) {
            return;
        }

        printf("%s/%u ", inet_ntop(r->rtm_family, RTA_DATA(tb[RTA_DST]), buf, sizeof(buf)), r->rtm_dst_len);

    } else if (r->rtm_dst_len) {
        printf("0/%u ", r->rtm_dst_len);
    } else {
        printf("default ");
    }

    if (tb[RTA_GATEWAY]) {
        printf("via %s", inet_ntop(r->rtm_family, RTA_DATA(tb[RTA_GATEWAY]), buf, sizeof(buf)));
        strcpy(ip, inet_ntop(r->rtm_family, RTA_DATA(tb[RTA_GATEWAY]), buf, sizeof(buf)));
    }

    if (tb[RTA_OIF]) {
        char if_nam_buf[IF_NAMESIZE];
        int ifidx = *(__u32 *)RTA_DATA(tb[RTA_OIF]);

        printf(" dev %s", if_indextoname(ifidx, if_nam_buf));
    }

    if (tb[RTA_GATEWAY] && tb[RTA_OIF]) {
        char if_nam_buf[IF_NAMESIZE];
        int ifidx = *(__u32 *)RTA_DATA(tb[RTA_OIF]);

        strcpy(ifname, if_indextoname(ifidx, if_nam_buf));
    }

    if (tb[RTA_SRC]) {
        printf("src %s", inet_ntop(r->rtm_family, RTA_DATA(tb[RTA_SRC]), buf, sizeof(buf)));
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int open_netlink()
{
    struct sockaddr_nl saddr;

    int sock = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_ROUTE);

    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("Failed to open netlink socket");
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&saddr, 0, sizeof(saddr));

    saddr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
    saddr.nl_pid = getpid();

    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr)) < 0) {
        perror("Failed to bind to netlink socket");
        close(sock);
        return -1;
    }

    return sock;
}

int do_route_dump_requst(int sock)
{
    struct {
        struct nlmsghdr nlh;
        struct rtmsg rtm;
    } nl_request;

    nl_request.nlh.nlmsg_type = RTM_GETROUTE;
    nl_request.nlh.nlmsg_flags = NLM_F_REQUEST | NLM_F_DUMP;
    nl_request.nlh.nlmsg_len = sizeof(nl_request);
    nl_request.nlh.nlmsg_seq = time(NULL);
    nl_request.rtm.rtm_family = AF_INET;

    return send(sock, &nl_request, sizeof(nl_request), 0);
}

int get_route_dump_response(int sock)
{
    struct sockaddr_nl nladdr;
    struct iovec iov;
    struct msghdr msg = {
        .msg_name = &nladdr,
        .msg_namelen = sizeof(nladdr),
        .msg_iov = &iov,
        .msg_iovlen = 1,
    };

    char *buf;
    int dump_intr = 0;

    int status = rtnl_recvmsg(sock, &msg, &buf);

    struct nlmsghdr *h = (struct nlmsghdr *)buf;
    int msglen = status;

    printf("Main routing table IPv4\n");

    while (NLMSG_OK(h, msglen)) {
        if (h->nlmsg_flags & NLM_F_DUMP_INTR) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Dump was interrupted\n");
            free(buf);
            return -1;
        }

        if (nladdr.nl_pid != 0) {
            continue;
        }

        if (h->nlmsg_type == NLMSG_ERROR) {
            perror("netlink reported error");
            free(buf);
        }

        print_route(h);

        h = NLMSG_NEXT(h, msglen);
    }

    free(buf);

    return status;
}


/*
 * Converts struct sockaddr with an IPv4 address to network byte order uin32_t.
 * Returns 0 on success.
 */
int int_ip4(struct sockaddr *addr, uint32_t *ip)
{
    if (addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        struct sockaddr_in *i = (struct sockaddr_in *) addr;
        *ip = i->sin_addr.s_addr;
        return 0;
    } else {
        err("Not AF_INET");
        return 1;
    }
}

/*
 * Formats sockaddr containing IPv4 address as human readable string.
 * Returns 0 on success.
 */
int format_ip4(struct sockaddr *addr, char *out)
{
    if (addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        struct sockaddr_in *i = (struct sockaddr_in *) addr;
        const char *ip = inet_ntoa(i->sin_addr);
        if (!ip) {
            return -2;
        } else {
            strcpy(out, ip);
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

/*
 * Writes interface IPv4 address as network byte order to ip.
 * Returns 0 on success.
 */
int get_if_ip4(int fd, const char *ifname, uint32_t *ip) {
    int err = -1;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
    if (strlen(ifname) > (IFNAMSIZ - 1)) {
        err("Too long interface name");
        goto out;
    }

    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, ifname);
    if (ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr) == -1) {
        perror("SIOCGIFADDR");
        goto out;
    }

    if (int_ip4(&ifr.ifr_addr, ip)) {
        goto out;
    }
    err = 0;
out:
    return err;
}

/*
 * Sends an ARP who-has request to dst_ip
 * on interface ifindex, using source mac src_mac and source ip src_ip.
 */
int send_arp(int fd, int ifindex, const unsigned char *src_mac, uint32_t src_ip, uint32_t dst_ip)
{
    int err = -1;
    unsigned char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

    struct sockaddr_ll socket_address;
    socket_address.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    socket_address.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ARP);
    socket_address.sll_ifindex = ifindex;
    socket_address.sll_hatype = htons(ARPHRD_ETHER);
    socket_address.sll_pkttype = (PACKET_BROADCAST);
    socket_address.sll_halen = MAC_LENGTH;
    socket_address.sll_addr[6] = 0x00;
    socket_address.sll_addr[7] = 0x00;

    struct ethhdr *send_req = (struct ethhdr *) buffer;
    struct arp_header *arp_req = (struct arp_header *) (buffer + ETH2_HEADER_LEN);
    int index;
    ssize_t ret, length = 0;

    //Broadcast
    memset(send_req->h_dest, 0xff, MAC_LENGTH);

    //Target MAC zero
    memset(arp_req->target_mac, 0x00, MAC_LENGTH);

    //Set source mac to our MAC address
    memcpy(send_req->h_source, src_mac, MAC_LENGTH);
    memcpy(arp_req->sender_mac, src_mac, MAC_LENGTH);
    memcpy(socket_address.sll_addr, src_mac, MAC_LENGTH);

    /* Setting protocol of the packet */
    send_req->h_proto = htons(ETH_P_ARP);

    /* Creating ARP request */
    arp_req->hardware_type = htons(HW_TYPE);
    arp_req->protocol_type = htons(ETH_P_IP);
    arp_req->hardware_len = MAC_LENGTH;
    arp_req->protocol_len = IPV4_LENGTH;
    arp_req->opcode = htons(ARP_REQUEST);

    debug("Copy IP address to arp_req");
    memcpy(arp_req->sender_ip, &src_ip, sizeof(uint32_t));
    memcpy(arp_req->target_ip, &dst_ip, sizeof(uint32_t));

    ret = sendto(fd, buffer, 42, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &socket_address, sizeof(socket_address));
    if (ret == -1) {
        perror("sendto():");
        goto out;
    }
    err = 0;
out:
    return err;
}

/*
 * Gets interface information by name:
 * IPv4
 * MAC
 * ifindex
 */
int get_if_info(const char *ifname, uint32_t *ip, char *mac, int *ifindex)
{
    debug("get_if_info for %s", ifname);
    int err = -1;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int sd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ARP));
    if (sd <= 0) {
        perror("socket()");
        goto out;
    }
    if (strlen(ifname) > (IFNAMSIZ - 1)) {
        printf("Too long interface name, MAX=%i\n", IFNAMSIZ - 1);
        goto out;
    }

    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, ifname);

    //Get interface index using name
    if (ioctl(sd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) == -1) {
        perror("SIOCGIFINDEX");
        goto out;
    }
    *ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    printf("interface index is %d\n", *ifindex);

    //Get MAC address of the interface
    if (ioctl(sd, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr) == -1) {
        perror("SIOCGIFINDEX");
        goto out;
    }

    //Copy mac address to output
    memcpy(mac, ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, MAC_LENGTH);

    if (get_if_ip4(sd, ifname, ip)) {
        goto out;
    }
    debug("get_if_info OK");

    err = 0;
out:
    if (sd > 0) {
        debug("Clean up temporary socket");
        close(sd);
    }
    return err;
}

/*
 * Creates a raw socket that listens for ARP traffic on specific ifindex.
 * Writes out the socket's FD.
 * Return 0 on success.
 */
int bind_arp(int ifindex, int *fd)
{
    debug("bind_arp: ifindex=%i", ifindex);
    int ret = -1;

    // Submit request for a raw socket descriptor.
    *fd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ARP));
    if (*fd < 1) {
        perror("socket()");
        goto out;
    }

    debug("Binding to ifindex %i", ifindex);
    struct sockaddr_ll sll;
    memset(&sll, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
    sll.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    sll.sll_ifindex = ifindex;
    if (bind(*fd, (struct sockaddr*) &sll, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll)) < 0) {
        perror("bind");
        goto out;
    }

    ret = 0;
out:
    if (ret && *fd > 0) {
        debug("Cleanup socket");
        close(*fd);
    }
    return ret;
}

/*
 * Reads a single ARP reply from fd.
 * Return 0 on success.
 */
int read_arp(int fd)
{
    debug("read_arp");
    int ret = -1;
    ssize_t length = recvfrom(fd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0, NULL, NULL);
    int index;
    if (length == -1) {
        perror("recvfrom()");
        goto out;
    }
    struct ethhdr *rcv_resp = (struct ethhdr *) buffer;
    if (ntohs(rcv_resp->h_proto) != PROTO_ARP) {
        debug("Not an ARP packet");
        goto out;
    }
    if (ntohs(arp_resp->opcode) != ARP_REPLY) {
        debug("Not an ARP reply");
        goto out;
    }
    debug("received ARP len=%ld", length);
    struct in_addr sender_a;
    memset(&sender_a, 0, sizeof(struct in_addr));
    memcpy(&sender_a.s_addr, arp_resp->sender_ip, sizeof(uint32_t));
    debug("Sender IP: %s", inet_ntoa(sender_a));

    debug("Sender MAC: %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X",
          arp_resp->sender_mac[0],
          arp_resp->sender_mac[1],
          arp_resp->sender_mac[2],
          arp_resp->sender_mac[3],
          arp_resp->sender_mac[4],
          arp_resp->sender_mac[5]);

    ret = 0;

out:
    return ret;
}

/*
 *
 * Sample code that sends an ARP who-has request on
 * interface <ifname> to IPv4 address <ip>.
 * Returns 0 on success.
 */
int test_arping(const char *ifname, const char *ip) {
    int ret = -1;
    uint32_t dst = inet_addr(ip);
    if (dst == 0 || dst == 0xffffffff) {
        printf("Invalid source IP\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int src;
    int ifindex;
    char mac[MAC_LENGTH];
    if (get_if_info(ifname, &src, mac, &ifindex)) {
        err("get_if_info failed, interface %s not found or no IP set?", ifname);
        goto out;
    }
    int arp_fd;
    if (bind_arp(ifindex, &arp_fd)) {
        err("Failed to bind_arp()");
        goto out;
    }

    if (send_arp(arp_fd, ifindex, mac, src, dst)) {
        err("Failed to send_arp");
        goto out;
    }

    while(1) {
        int r = read_arp(arp_fd);
        if (r == 0) {
            info("Got reply, break out");
            break;
        }
    }

    ret = 0;
out:
    if (arp_fd) {
        close(arp_fd);
        arp_fd = 0;
    }
    return ret;
}

/*
    Generic checksum calculation function
*/
unsigned short csum(unsigned short *ptr,int nbytes) 
{
    register long sum;
    unsigned short oddbyte;
    register short answer;

    sum=0;
    while(nbytes>1) {
        sum+=*ptr++;
        nbytes-=2;
    }
    if(nbytes==1) {
        oddbyte=0;
        *((u_char*)&oddbyte)=*(u_char*)ptr;
        sum+=oddbyte;
    }

    sum = (sum>>16)+(sum & 0xffff);
    sum = sum + (sum>>16);
    answer=(short)~sum;
    
    return(answer);
}


int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    uint32_t size;
    struct sockaddr_ll my_addr[MAX_CONNECTIONS], peer_addr;
    int i_ifindex;
    int ec;
    struct ifreq s_ifr; /* points to one interface returned from ioctl */
    int tmp;
    FILE * fp;
    char server[254];
    int count = 0;
    int first_time = 1;
    int z;
    int first_mmap = 1;
    
    #define HWADDR_len 6
    #define IP_len 4
    int s,s2,i;
    struct ifreq ifr,ifr2;
    int ret = -1;
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <INPUT_FILE>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
//  const char *ifname = argv[2];
//  const char *ip = argv[3];
    int nl_sock = open_netlink();

    if (do_route_dump_requst(nl_sock) < 0) {
        perror("Failed to perfom request");
        close(nl_sock);
        return -1;
    }

    get_route_dump_response(nl_sock);

    close (nl_sock);
    
    test_arping(ifname, ip);

    
    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    s2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, ifname);
    strcpy(ifr2.ifr_name, ifname);
    ioctl(s, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr);
    ioctl(s2, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr2);
    struct sockaddr_in* ipaddr = (struct sockaddr_in*)&ifr2.ifr_addr;
    close(s);

    while (!done)
    {
        if (first_time)
        {
            if (count < MAX_CONNECTIONS) z = count;
        }

        count++;
        if (count == 10000) break;
    
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (!fp)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        fd_socket[z] = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW|SOCK_NONBLOCK, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
        if(fd_socket[z] == -1)
        {
            perror("socket");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    
        /* clear structure */
        memset(&my_addr[z], 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
        my_addr[z].sll_family = PF_PACKET;
        my_addr[z].sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_ALL);
    
        str_devname = ifname;
        //strcpy (str_devname, ifname);
        
        /* initialize interface struct */
        strncpy (s_ifr.ifr_name, str_devname, sizeof(s_ifr.ifr_name));
    
        /* Get the broad cast address */
        ec = ioctl(fd_socket[z], SIOCGIFINDEX, &s_ifr);
        if(ec == -1)
        {
            perror("iotcl");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    
        /* update with interface index */
        i_ifindex = s_ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    
        s_ifr.ifr_mtu = 7200;
        /* update the mtu through ioctl */
        ec = ioctl(fd_socket[z], SIOCSIFMTU, &s_ifr);
        if(ec == -1)
        {
            perror("iotcl");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    
        /* set sockaddr info */
        memset(&my_addr[z], 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
        my_addr[z].sll_family = AF_PACKET;
        my_addr[z].sll_protocol = ETH_P_ALL;
        my_addr[z].sll_ifindex = i_ifindex;
    
        /* bind port */
        if (bind(fd_socket[z], (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr[z], sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll)) == -1)
        {
            perror("bind");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    
        /* prepare Tx ring request */
        s_packet_req.tp_block_size = c_buffer_sz;
        s_packet_req.tp_frame_size = c_buffer_sz;
        s_packet_req.tp_block_nr = c_buffer_nb;
        s_packet_req.tp_frame_nr = c_buffer_nb;
    
        /* calculate memory to mmap in the kernel */
        size = s_packet_req.tp_block_size * s_packet_req.tp_block_nr;
    
        /* set packet loss option */
        tmp = mode_loss;
        if (setsockopt(fd_socket[z], SOL_PACKET, PACKET_LOSS, (char *)&tmp, sizeof(tmp))<0)
        {
            perror("setsockopt: PACKET_LOSS");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
 
        /* send TX ring request */
        if (setsockopt(fd_socket[z], SOL_PACKET, PACKET_TX_RING, (char *)&s_packet_req, sizeof(s_packet_req))<0)
        {
            perror("setsockopt: PACKET_TX_RING");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    
        /* change send buffer size */
        if(c_sndbuf_sz) {
            printf("send buff size = %d\n", c_sndbuf_sz);
            if (setsockopt(fd_socket[z], SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &c_sndbuf_sz, sizeof(c_sndbuf_sz))< 0)
            {
                perror("getsockopt: SO_SNDBUF");
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }
    
        /* get data offset */
        data_offset = TPACKET_HDRLEN - sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll);
    
        /* mmap Tx ring buffers memory */
        ps_header_start = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd_socket[z], 0);
        if (ps_header_start == (void*)-1)
        {
            perror("mmap");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    
    
        int i,j;
        int i_index = 0;
        char * data;
        int first_loop = 1;
        struct tpacket_hdr * ps_header;
        int ec_send = 0;
 
        for(i=1; i <= c_packet_nb; i++)
        {
            int i_index_start = i_index;
            int loop = 1;
 
            /* get free buffer */
            do {
                ps_header = ((struct tpacket_hdr *)((void *)ps_header_start + (c_buffer_sz*i_index)));
                data = ((void*) ps_header) + data_offset;
                switch((volatile uint32_t)ps_header->tp_status)
                {
                    case TP_STATUS_AVAILABLE:
                        /* fill data in buffer */
                        if(first_loop) {
                            //Datagram to represent the packet
                            char datagram[4096] , source_ip[32] , *data2, *pseudogram;
    
                            //zero out the packet buffer
                            memset (datagram, 0, 4096);
    
                            //Ethernet header
                            struct ether_header *eh = (struct ether_header *) datagram;
        
                            //IP header
                            struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *) (datagram + sizeof (struct ether_header));
    
                            //TCP header
                            struct tcphdr *tcph = (struct tcphdr *) (datagram + sizeof (struct ether_header) + sizeof (struct ip));
                            struct sockaddr_in sin;
                            struct pseudo_header psh;
    
                            //Data part
                            data2 = datagram + sizeof(struct ether_header) + sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr);
                            strcpy(data2 , "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    
                            //some address resolution
                            strcpy(source_ip , inet_ntoa(ipaddr->sin_addr));
                            sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
                            sin.sin_port = htons(80);
                            if (fscanf(fp, "%253s", server) == 1)
                                sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr (server);   
                            else
                            {
                                done = 1;
                                break;
                            }
                        
                            //Fill in the Ethernet Header
                            //eh->ether_dhost[0] = 0x70;
                            //eh->ether_dhost[1] = 0x97;
                            //eh->ether_dhost[2] = 0x41;
                            //eh->ether_dhost[3] = 0x4b;
                            //eh->ether_dhost[4] = 0x1e;
                            //eh->ether_dhost[5] = 0xc2;
                            eh->ether_dhost[0] = arp_resp->sender_mac[0];
                            eh->ether_dhost[1] = arp_resp->sender_mac[1];
                            eh->ether_dhost[2] = arp_resp->sender_mac[2];
                            eh->ether_dhost[3] = arp_resp->sender_mac[3];
                            eh->ether_dhost[4] = arp_resp->sender_mac[4];
                            eh->ether_dhost[5] = arp_resp->sender_mac[5];

                            memcpy(eh->ether_shost, ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data, HWADDR_len);
                            eh->ether_type = 0x0008;
    
                            //Fill in the IP Header
                            iph->ihl = 5;
                            iph->version = 4;
                            iph->tos = 0;
                            iph->tot_len = sizeof (struct iphdr) + sizeof (struct tcphdr) + strlen(data);
                            iph->id = htonl (54321);    //Id of this packet
                            iph->frag_off = 0;
                            iph->ttl = 255;
                            iph->protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
                            iph->check = 0;     //Set to 0 before calculating checksum
                            iph->saddr = inet_addr ( source_ip );   //Spoof the source ip address
                            iph->daddr = sin.sin_addr.s_addr;
    
                            //Ip checksum
                            iph->check = csum ((unsigned short *) datagram, iph->tot_len);
    
                            //TCP Header
                            tcph->source = htons (1234);
                            tcph->dest = htons (80);
                            tcph->seq = 0;
                            tcph->ack_seq = 0;
                            tcph->doff = 5; //tcp header size
                            tcph->fin=0;
                            tcph->syn=1;
                            tcph->rst=0;
                            tcph->psh=0;
                            tcph->ack=0;
                            tcph->urg=0;
                            tcph->window = htons (5840);    // maximum allowed window size 
                            tcph->check = 0;    //leave checksum 0 now, filled later by pseudo header
                            tcph->urg_ptr = 0;

                            //Now the TCP checksum
                            psh.source_address = inet_addr( source_ip );
                            psh.dest_address = sin.sin_addr.s_addr;
                            psh.placeholder = 0;
                            psh.protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
                            psh.tcp_length = htons(sizeof(struct tcphdr) + strlen(data) );
    
                            int psize = sizeof(struct pseudo_header) + sizeof(struct tcphdr) + strlen(data);
                            pseudogram = malloc(psize);
        
                            memcpy(pseudogram , (char*) &psh , sizeof (struct pseudo_header));
                            memcpy(pseudogram + sizeof(struct pseudo_header) , tcph , sizeof(struct tcphdr) + strlen(data));
    
                            tcph->check = csum( (unsigned short*) pseudogram , psize);
                        
                            memcpy(data, datagram, 4096);
                            free(pseudogram);
//                      for(j=0;j<c_packet_sz;j++)
//                          data[j] = j;
                        }
                        loop = 0;
                    break;
 
                    case TP_STATUS_WRONG_FORMAT:
                        printf("An error has occured during transfer\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    break;
 
                    default:
                        /* nothing to do => schedule : useful if no SMP */
                        usleep(0);
                        break;
                }
            }
            while(loop == 1);
 
            i_index ++;
            if(i_index >= c_buffer_nb)
            {
                i_index = 0;
                first_loop = 0;
            }
 
            /* update packet len */
            ps_header->tp_len = c_packet_sz;
            /* set header flag to USER (trigs xmit)*/
            ps_header->tp_status = TP_STATUS_SEND_REQUEST;
 
            /* if smp mode selected */
            if(!mode_thread)
            {
                /* send all packets */
                if( ((i&c_send_mask)==0) || (ec_send < 0) || (i == c_packet_nb) )
                {
                    /* send all buffers with TP_STATUS_SEND_REQUEST */
                    /* Don't wait end of transfer */
                    //ec_send = (int) task_send((void*)0);
                }
            }
            else if(c_error) {
 
                if(i == (c_packet_nb/2))
                {
                    int ec_close;
                
                    if(c_error == 1) {
                        ec_close = close(fd_socket[z]);
                    }
                    if(c_error == 2) {
                        if (setsockopt(fd_socket[z], SOL_PACKET, PACKET_TX_RING, (char *)&s_packet_req, sizeof(s_packet_req))<0)
                        {
                            perror("setsockopt: PACKET_TX_RING");
                            //return EXIT_FAILURE;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    
        //int ec_send;
        static int total=0;
        int blocking = 1;
        
        /* send all buffers with TP_STATUS_SEND_REQUEST */
        /* Wait end of transfer */
        ec_send = sendto(fd_socket[z],NULL,0,(blocking? 0 : MSG_DONTWAIT),(struct sockaddr *) ps_sockaddr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));
        
        if(ec_send < 0) {
            perror("sendto");
        }
        else if ( ec_send == 0 ) {
            /* nothing to do => schedule : useful if no SMP */
            usleep(0);
        }
        else {
            total += ec_send/(c_packet_sz);
            printf("send %d packets (+%d bytes)\n",total, ec_send);
            fflush(0);
        }
        //ps_header_start = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd_socket[z], 0);
        if (munmap(ps_header_start, size) == -1)
        {
            perror("munmap");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }       
    
        close(fd_socket[z]);
 
    }
    return 1;
}
```