# Raw Socket not sending on WSL

Tags: c, sockets, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Using WSL2, and a raw sockets implementation, I cannot seem to send any packets.  I cannot include all the code as it is a big driver, but I will try include the relevant parts below.  I don't think there is anything wrong with the socket code, but maybe my socket configuration or something.

In tcpdump I can see my packets being sent, but they do not show in up Wireshark on the vEthernet(WSL) interface, or the PCs Ethernet interface that is the only internet connection.

The socket is created with:

```
    int sock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
```

The send function uses the code below.  sa.sll_ifindex is set to the index of the eth0 AF_PACKET network interface (6 in my case).  sa.sll_addr is set to the MAC address of the same interface.  The packet data is constructed by lwIP IP stack.  sendto always succeeds, returning the full number of bytes sent.

```
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    sa.sll_halen = netif->hwaddr_len;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < netif->hwaddr_len; i++)
    {
        sa.sll_addr[i] = netif->hwaddr[i];
    }
    sa.sll_ifindex = ctx->HostInterfaceIndex;
    sa.sll_protocol = htons(ETH_P_IP);
    ssize_t sent = sendto(ctx->RawSockHandle, buf, p->tot_len, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa));
```

When application code is sending a DNS query, I see the following in netcap:

```
14:01:01.101480 IP 172.17.44.146.10924 > dns.google.domain: 55249+ A? test.site.io. (35)
14:01:01.452154 IP 172.17.44.146.10924 > dns.google.domain: 55249+ A? test.site.io. (35)
14:01:02.452560 IP 172.17.44.146.10924 > dns.google.domain: 55249+ A? test.site.io. (35)
14:01:04.452146 IP 172.17.44.146.10924 > dns.google.domain: 55249+ A? test.site.io. (35)
14:01:07.452520 IP 172.17.44.146.10924 > one.one.one.one.domain: 55249+ A? test.site.io. (35)
14:01:08.452721 IP 172.17.44.146.10924 > one.one.one.one.domain: 55249+ A? test.site.io. (35)
14:01:09.452102 IP 172.17.44.146.10924 > one.one.one.one.domain: 55249+ A? test.site.io. (35)
14:01:11.452584 IP 172.17.44.146.10924 > one.one.one.one.domain: 55249+ A? test.site.io. (35)
```

So, it appears my packets are making it into the WSL eth0 interface, but not making it any further.

Any suggestions on what I can do to diagnose this.  I can paste additional code if needed, just ask.  I tried to keep it simple.

Comment: I think I may have just spotted my problem.  The destination address I am sending to is that of the eth0 interface.  I think it is meant to be the actual destination MAC address of the remote.  But, how would I know the remote address on WSL?

Comment: Well, how would you do it on a _native_ linux install? Did you try (e.g.) `getaddrinfo`, etc. to get the _IP_ (not _MAC_) address of google.com (e.g. `142.251.35.164`)? You may want to start with `AF_INET` first, to verify things and then graduate to `AF_PACKET` when the simpler/regular connect is working.

Comment: "*But, how would I know the remote address on WSL*". You can't know the remote MAC. That's not how packets are routed. You need to get the MAC of the next hop. Which is usually a router. That information is obtained from ARP (Address Resolution Protocol).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  There appear to be methods using netlink sockets that allow finding the MAC address of the default route but I haven't got that far yet.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70610396/how-do-i-get-the-gateway-mac-address-in-c-on-linux
For now I am trying to go down another layer and read the Ethernet packets and have lwIP do ARP.  But I think that would still be no good as doesn't DHCP usually provide the IP address of the default gateway?

Answer (score 1):

Following [this how-to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/get-started/create-a-virtual-switch-for-hyper-v-virtual-machines) I connected the virtual switch to the external, real, LAN switch and then raw Ethernet packets sent to the LAN's MAC from WSL2 Linux side appear in Windows side Wireshark.

Virtual Switch configuration form:

[image: Virtual Switch configuration form]